# ELF linking with other object files

Tags: linker, elf

I have a set of object files and a Thirdparty elf file. I would like to know is it possible to link the object files with the elf file and create a final executable file? I am using Greenhills compiler. Let me know if this option available with this compiler tool chain.

Comment: If your object files are [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) object files and your Thirdparty ELF file is also
an ELF object file, or an ELF shared library, and if they target the same architecture, then yes; otherwise no.

Comment: What is the output from `file /path/to/third-party/elf/file` ? The answer depends on whether it's a relocatable object file, a shared library, an executable, or something else (all of these could be ELF files, so just saying "ELF file" doesn't say much). Please edit your question with the additional info.